Diagonal set is not measurable
The following is an exercise from probability theory, which indicates that the section of non-measurable set can be measurable.

Problem
Let $\Omega$ be an uncountable set,
$$
\mathcal{F} = \{A\subset \Omega, A \ or\  A^C \ is \ countable\},
$$
then $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Show that the diagonal set $\triangle = \{(\omega, \omega), \omega \in \Omega\}$ is not measurable(i.e. not in $\mathcal{F}\times \mathcal{F}$).

The answer from Lukas Geyer  contains a very similar problem but the method seems not to be suitable for solving this problem. I searched online and found a possible way---to prove
$$
\mathcal{F}\times \mathcal{F} = \mathcal{A}_1 \cup \mathcal{A}_2,
$$
while
$$
\mathcal{A}_1 = \{ \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (A_n \times \{y_n\})\cup \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (\{x_n\}\times B_n ) \cup 
\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (C_n \times {D_n})\},
$$
and
$$
\mathcal{A}_2 = \{ \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (A_n \times \{y_n\})\cup \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (\{x_n\}\times B_n )\},
$$
where $x_n, n\geq 1$ are distinct and $y_n, n\geq 1$ are distinct and $C_n^C,D_n^C$ are countable.
The difficulty is to show $\mathcal{A}_1 \cup \mathcal{A}_2$ is close under complement.
Solved
As @Ramiro's comment indicate A question about $\sigma$-algebra determine whether the diagonal it is measurable.
A little complement is to give a sketch of $\nu^*(\Delta^c) = 1$ .
Let $\Delta^c \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \times B_n$. Suppose that $\mu(A_n) \mu(B_n) = 0, n\geq 1$, there are three situations:

$A_n, B_n$ are countable.
$A_n$ is countable and $B_n$ is uncountable, replace $B_n$ by $\Omega$.
$A_n$ is uncountable and $B_n$ is countable, replace $A_n$ by $\Omega$.

Now we get
$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \times B_n = \left(\bigcup_{n_1=1}^\infty A_{n_1} \times B_{n_1}\right) \cup \left(\bigcup_{n_2=1}^\infty A_{n_2} \times \Omega\right) \cup \left(\bigcup_{n_3=1}^\infty \Omega \times B_{n_3}\right).
$$
So we have
$$
\left[\left(\bigcup_{n_2=1}^\infty A_{n_2} \right)^c \times \left(\bigcup_{n_3=1}^\infty B_{n_3}\right)^c\right]
\cap \Delta^c \subset \left(\bigcup_{n_1=1}^\infty A_{n_1} \times B_{n_1}\right).
$$
However, the left side set is uncountable and the right side set is countable---a contradiction! Then $\nu^*(\Delta^c) \geq 1$ .
On the other side, $\nu^*(\Delta^c) \leq 1$ is obvious from the definition of $\nu^*$ .

Notice that $\Delta$ and $\Omega$ are in bijection: $w \mapsto (w,w)$. I think you can easily map $\Omega$ injectively to a subset of the complement of $\Delta$... a vertical line is a good start.

@AndréCaldas sorry, I don't understand your method, could you give more details? How to use the bijection?

See this question, which shows that the diagonal is not measurable in an even larger $\sigma$-algebra. (The question has $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$, but the answers apply to any uncountable set.)

@Ramiro Thanks， there is no difference. I get it！

@Vanellope: sorry, I didn't realize the $\sigma$-algebra was in $\Omega$, not $\Omega \times \Omega$.
